# Apache 2.2 localhost VirtualHosts problems

Tags: macos, apache2, virtualhost, apache

I am trying to setup my dev machine with virtual hosts so I can access my development projects with a simple url, like http:// project.dev/ rather that a whole http:// 127.0.0.1/dev/path/to/root/of/project/ type of url.

Now, I'm aware there are many tutorials and questions already answered about this, but after trying many of them, I feel like I'm running in circles here.

The problem is simple: after setting up my hosts file and my virtual hosts, any attempt to access a virtual hosts irremediably displays the content of my **server** DocumentRoot.

my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mydomain.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/pilot/Sites/
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/pilot/Sites/devel/vytamin/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

I precise that the httpd-vhosts.conf file IS loaded in my httpd.conf and I do get a warning if I point the virtual host document root to a wrong folder.

I made a try setting the localhost virtual host to the following, without any success.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/pilot/Sites/devel
</Virtualhost>
```

The following URLS all display the DocumentRoot of my server defined in my httpd.conf file, and seem to ignore the DocumentRoot defined in my VirtualHosts.

```
http:// 127.0.0.1/
http:// localhost/
http:// mydomain.dev/
```

I'm running Apache2.2 on Mac OSX 10.5 Leopard, but not the one shipped with mac os. I compiled my own under /usr/local/apache2 and web sharing **IS disabled**

I can't see anything wrong with my set up so I hope the community will!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ooops, Sorry for that, thanks Yannick for pointing this out, will ask it there as well.
cheers!

Comment: I thought it was kind of weird that this question had zero answers when I knew I'd already answered it... I answered the version over on Serverfault.

Comment: :) I'm new to the sites and trying to muddle my way through! Will get there! But thanks for the suggestions. I read somewhere that someone had a similar problem and it got solved without intervention after rebooting the machine. That made it click!

Comment: I had a problem and adding this line solved it:
NameVirtualHost *:80

What is that exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the problem!

The configuration above is perfectly fine, it was just that my apache was not restarting properly.
Neither `apache_ctl graceful` or `apache_ctl restart` was terminating all httpd processes I have running, therefore failing to reload properly the changes in my configuration files.
Once I killed the remaining processes and **really** restarted apache, it worked...

Solved, but I feel dumb to have found that!

Now I have a daemon situation to solve!

Comment: What does 'apache_ctl status' return, it could be that the Pidfile that apache is creating and the one apache_ctl is looking for are different.